# Python doctest - example failure - need answers

Tags: python, doctest

```
def check_TLA(w1, w2, w3):
'''
>>> check_TLA("Game" , "of", "thrones")
'GOT'
>>> check_TLA("impressive", "optical", "under")
'IOU'
'''



print(w1[0].upper() + w2[0].upper()+ w3[0].upper())


if __name__ == "__main__":
  import doctest
  doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

I've been stuck on this question for a long time, it wants me to split the words up and return it back with an upper case 'GOT' and 'IOU'.

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything. If you print a string directly it won't have the quotes.

Comment: Replace `print` with `return`?

Comment: thanks! yeah, all I had to do was use return instead of print.